# What is the simplest way to create several HSQLDB server databases?

Tags: java, sql, database, linux, hsqldb

Is there a simpler way? To start many database we can create simple file "*start.sh*"

Before start to use create separate folders for each databases.

*/opt/db/trunk*

*/opt/db/master*

Next one copy to "*start.sh*":

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp ./hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar  org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:/opt/db/master/master --dbname.0 master --database.1 file:/opt/db/trunk/trunk --dbname.1 trunk
```

Make this file to be executable:

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

Start to run:

```
$ ./hsqdb.sh
```

Output:

```
...
[Server@15c7850]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:/opt/db/trunk/trunk, alias=trunk] opened sucessfully in 426 ms.
[Server@15c7850]: Database [index=1, id=1, db=file:/opt/db/master/master, alias=master] opened sucessfully in 128 ms.
...
[Server@15c7850]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

So you will get two databases with aliases: **trunk** and **master**

Example how to configure HSQL Database Manager:

> Type:    HSQL Database engine server
>
> Driver:  org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
>
> URL:     jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/**trunk**
>
> User:    SA
>
> Password:

You can change the alias trunk to another alias

JDBC URL connection:

> jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/**trunk**
>
> jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/**master**

Comment: This looks like a tutorial, not a question.

Comment: Can we create many databases another(simplest) way?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a more generalized script to start the databases.

Some thoughts on the steps the script would have to do

1. accept a list of parameters
2. declare `start_string`. initialize with `java -cp ./hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar  org.hsqldb.server.Server`
3. first parameter could be the path of the folder that contains the folders for each DB (e.g. `/opt/db/`)

   - all parameters after first are considered as DB names
4. iterate over all DB names and create DB folder in parent folder (1st param) if it does not already exist

   - append `--database.<counter_variable> file:<parent_folder>/<db_name>/<db_name> --dbname.<counter_variable> <db_name>` to `start_string`
5. execute `start_string`

You can then pass the list of DB names to your program, which will connect to them using URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/<db_name>`